# how to read firebases response before entering break mode

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-authentication

I need to read res and content as strings  before the application enters break mode which I believe have the errors in them so I can inform the users of what they need to fix (wrong password, invalid email, or account already taken)in toast form.

tried reading the string right after receiving firebases response but it still enters break mode. also tried try and catch which made the line of code that logs the user in never execute. I could have been using them wrong im a beginner programmer.

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, IOnClickListener

{

    Button login;
    Button forgotPassword;
    Button signUp;
    EditText Lemail;
    EditText Lpassword;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        login = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLILogIn);
        signUp =  FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLISignup);
        Lemail = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etEmailLogIn);
        Lpassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etPasswordLogIn);
        forgotPassword = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLIForgotpassword);

        login.Click += new EventHandler(delegate (Object o, EventArgs a)
        {
            SignInAsync(Lemail.Text, Lpassword.Text);
        });

        signUp.SetOnClickListener(this);
        forgotPassword.SetOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    }

    //
    //firebase auth initial token generation start
    //

    public AuthenticationHeaderValue token { get; private set; }
   /*

    private async void AcsessFireBaseAsync()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { DefaultRequestHeaders = {Authorization = token } })

        {

            try
            {
                var res = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://myapp-6ha3a.firebaseio.com/");
                var content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

            catch (Exception ex0)
            {
                string error0 = ex0.ToString();
                Toast.MakeText(this, error0, ToastLength.Long);
            }

         }

    }
    */

    private async void AcsessFireBaseAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient() { DefaultRequestHeaders = { Authorization = token } };
        var res = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://myapp-6ha3a.firebaseio.com/");
        var content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        checkresponse(res.ToString() , content.ToString());
    }
    private void checkresponse(string Res ,string Content)
    {
        if (Res != null && Content != null)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, Res + Content, ToastLength.Long);



        }

    }

    public async void SignInAsync(string Email, string Passowrd)
    {
        async Task<string> SignInWithEmailAndPassword(string email, string password)
        {
            var user = await FirebaseAuth.Instance.
                            SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
            var token = await user.User.GetIdTokenAsync(false);
            return token.Token;


        }
        AcsessFireBaseAsync();


            await SignInWithEmailAndPassword(Lemail.Text, Lpassword.Text);
        }


    /*
    public async void SignInAsync(string Email, string Password)
    {
        var user = await FirebaseAuth.Instance.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(Email, Password);
        var _token = await user.User.GetIdTokenAsync(false);
        token = _token.Token;
        AcsessFireBaseAsync();
    }
    */
    //
    //firebase auth token generation end
    //,
    //
    //Onlick listener interface
    //
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        if (v.Id == Resource.Id.btnLISignup)
        {
            StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(activity_main)));
        }
        if (v.Id == Resource.Id.btnLIForgotpassword)
        {
            StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(forgotPassword)));
        }
    }
    //
    //Onlick listener interface
    //
}
```

Xamarin

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#FF8800"
android:weightSum="100"
android:gravity="center">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/test"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"     
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />

        </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="12"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">    
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/boxstyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="37"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <TextView
            android:text="Log In"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textColor="#808080"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="email"
            android:background="@drawable/edttxtstyle"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="#FF8800"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="16"
            android:id="@+id/etEmailLogIn" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

        <EditText
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="password"
            android:background="@drawable/edttxtstyle"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="#FF8800"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="16"
            android:id="@+id/etPasswordLogIn" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="16"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
            <Button
                android:text="SignUp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="@drawable/nvbuttonstyle"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:id="@+id/btnLISignup" />
               <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="3"/>
            <Button
                android:text="Forgot Password?"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="@drawable/nvbuttonstyle"
                android:layout_weight="30"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btnLIForgotpassword" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="16"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <Button
                android:text="Log in"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:background="@drawable/slcstyle"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:id="@+id/btnLILogIn" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[break mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVfkg.png)

Comment: I am confused with what you said,what is your specific problem?

Comment: that when user gets wrong password or other mistakes I cant display the error to the user before it goes into break mode

Comment: Where is the `break mode` ?I don't quite understand.

Comment: i added a link to a picture @jessieZhang